# convert list of elements with repeating names to data.frame in r

Tags: r, list

I have a list of elements with repeating names

```
l <- list(name = c("lol", "kek", "pip"),
          values = c(1,2,3),
          name = c("raph", "mike", "leo"),
          values = c(4,2,1))
```

How to convert it to a data frame like this in the simplest way?

```
data.frame(name = c("lol", "kek", "pip", "raph", "mike", "leo"),
           values = c(1,2,3,4,2,1))

  name values
1  lol      1
2  kek      2
3  pip      3
4 raph      4
5 mike      2
6  leo      1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in Base R you can do:

```
unstack(stack(l))
  name values
1  lol      1
2  kek      2
3  pip      3
4 raph      4
5 mike      2
6  leo      1
```

To maintain the underlying data type, use:

```
type.convert(unstack(stack(l)), as.is =TRUE)
  name values
1  lol      1
2  kek      2
3  pip      3
4 raph      4
5 mike      2
6  leo      1
```

Answer (score 4):

`split` by the repeated `names()`, and `unlist` each created group of `list`s:

```
data.frame(lapply(split(l, names(l)), unlist))
#  name values
#1  lol      1
#2  kek      2
#3  pip      3
#4 raph      4
#5 mike      2
#6  leo      1
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution iterates over unique names of `l` and uses `unlist()` to combine all elements with each name into a single vector. The resulting list is then converted to a dataframe.

```
names(l) |>
  unique() |>
  setNames(nm = _) |>
  lapply(\(nm) unlist(l[names(l) == nm])) |>
  as.data.frame()
```

```
  name values
1  lol      1
2  kek      2
3  pip      3
4 raph      4
5 mike      2
6  leo      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `stack` and `split`:

```
data.frame(with(stack(l), split(values, ind)))

#    name     values
# 1  lol      1
# 2  kek      2
# 3  pip      3
# 4  raph     4
# 5  mike     2
# 6  leo      1
```

Comment: The downside of the `stack` is that `output$values` is now numbers stored as character strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for duplicated and non-duplicated names:

```r
dups <- duplicated(names(l))
rbind(
  data.frame(l[!dups]),
  data.frame(l[dups])
)
```

```r
  name values
1  lol      1
2  kek      2
3  pip      3
4 raph      4
5 mike      2
6  leo      1
```

Comment: It will work on OP's example and is an interesting approach, but unfortunately falls over if any of the pairs of `name`/`values` have different lengths to other pairs. E.g. `l <- list(name = c("lol", "kek", "pip","ayy"), values = c(1,2,3,4), name = c("raph", "mike", "leo"), values = c(4,2,1))`

Comment: @thelatemail That was a good observation. I've updated the solution to cater for pairs of different lengths.